How to configure SPM in Jaeger?
Good day everyone, i have tried to setup the SPM monitor on recently but unfortunely it's showed no data on the ui page. All the configuration is based on this repo: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/connector/spanmetricsconnector#more-examples
Go code
// Copyright The OpenTelemetry Authors
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// Example using OTLP exporters + collector + third-party backends. For
// information about using the exporter, see:
// https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp?tab=doc#example-package-Insecure
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure"

    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/attribute"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlpmetric/otlpmetricgrpc"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlptrace/otlptracegrpc"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/propagation"
    sdkmetric "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/metric"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/resource"
    sdktrace "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace"
    semconv "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv/v1.25.0"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace"
)

var serviceName = semconv.ServiceNameKey.String("test-service")

// Initialize a gRPC connection to be used by both the tracer and meter
// providers.
func initConn() (*grpc.ClientConn, error) {
    // It connects the OpenTelemetry Collector through local gRPC connection.
    // You may replace `localhost:4317` with your endpoint.
    conn, err := grpc.NewClient("localhost:4317",
        // Note the use of insecure transport here. TLS is recommended in production.
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create gRPC connection to collector: %w", err)
    }

    return conn, err
}

// Initializes an OTLP exporter, and configures the corresponding trace provider.
func initTracerProvider(ctx context.Context, res *resource.Resource, conn *grpc.ClientConn) (func(context.Context) error, error) {
    // Set up a trace exporter
    traceExporter, err := otlptracegrpc.New(ctx, otlptracegrpc.WithGRPCConn(conn))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create trace exporter: %w", err)
    }

    // Register the trace exporter with a TracerProvider, using a batch
    // span processor to aggregate spans before export.
    bsp := sdktrace.NewBatchSpanProcessor(traceExporter)
    tracerProvider := sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        sdktrace.WithSampler(sdktrace.AlwaysSample()),
        sdktrace.WithResource(res),
        sdktrace.WithSpanProcessor(bsp),
    )
    otel.SetTracerProvider(tracerProvider)

    // Set global propagator to tracecontext (the default is no-op).
    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.TraceContext{})

    // Shutdown will flush any remaining spans and shut down the exporter.
    return tracerProvider.Shutdown, nil
}

// Initializes an OTLP exporter, and configures the corresponding meter provider.
func initMeterProvider(ctx context.Context, res *resource.Resource, conn *grpc.ClientConn) (func(context.Context) error, error) {
    metricExporter, err := otlpmetricgrpc.New(ctx, otlpmetricgrpc.WithGRPCConn(conn))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create metrics exporter: %w", err)
    }

    meterProvider := sdkmetric.NewMeterProvider(
        sdkmetric.WithReader(sdkmetric.NewPeriodicReader(metricExporter)),
        sdkmetric.WithResource(res),
    )
    otel.SetMeterProvider(meterProvider)

    return meterProvider.Shutdown, nil
}

func main() {
    log.Printf("Waiting for connection...")

    ctx, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), os.Interrupt)
    defer cancel()

    conn, err := initConn()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    res, err := resource.New(ctx,
        resource.WithAttributes(
            // The service name used to display traces in backends
            serviceName,
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    shutdownTracerProvider, err := initTracerProvider(ctx, res, conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := shutdownTracerProvider(ctx); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to shutdown TracerProvider: %s", err)
        }
    }()

    shutdownMeterProvider, err := initMeterProvider(ctx, res, conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := shutdownMeterProvider(ctx); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to shutdown MeterProvider: %s", err)
        }
    }()

    tracer := otel.Tracer("test-tracer")
    meter := otel.Meter("test-meter")

    // Attributes represent additional key-value descriptors that can be bound
    // to a metric observer or recorder.
    commonAttrs := []attribute.KeyValue{
        attribute.String("attrA", "chocolate"),
        attribute.String("attrB", "raspberry"),
        attribute.String("attrC", "vanilla"),
    }

    runCount, err := meter.Int64Counter("run", metric.WithDescription("The number of times the iteration ran"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Work begins
    ctx, span := tracer.Start(
        ctx,
        "CollectorExporter-Example",
        trace.WithAttributes(commonAttrs...))
    defer span.End()
    for i := 0; i < 1; i++ {
        _, iSpan := tracer.Start(ctx, fmt.Sprintf("Sample-%d", i))
        runCount.Add(ctx, 1, metric.WithAttributes(commonAttrs...))
        log.Printf("Doing really hard work (%d / 10)\n", i+1)

        <-time.After(time.Second)
        iSpan.End()
    }

    log.Printf("Done!")
}

docker-compose.yml
# Copyright The OpenTelemetry Authors
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

services:
  otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:latest
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector.yaml:/etc/otel-collector.yaml
    ports:
      - 4317:4317
      - 8889:8889

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.52.0
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    volumes:
      - "./jaeger-ui.json:/etc/jaeger/jaeger-ui.json"
    command: --query.ui-config /etc/jaeger/jaeger-ui.json
    environment:
      - METRICS_STORAGE_TYPE=prometheus
      - PROMETHEUS_SERVER_URL=http://prometheus:9090
      - PROMETHEUS_QUERY_SUPPORT_SPANMETRICS_CONNECTOR=true
      - PROMETHEUS_QUERY_NAMESPACE=testapp

      - PROMETHEUS_QUERY_NORMALIZE_CALLS=true
      - PROMETHEUS_QUERY_NORMALIZE_DURATION=true
    ports:
      - 16686:16686
      - 16687:16687

jaeger-ui.json
{
  "monitor": {
    "menuEnabled": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "menuEnabled": true
  }
}

otel-collector.yaml
# Copyright The OpenTelemetry Authors
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
processors:
extensions:
  health_check: {}
exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: jaeger:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true
  prometheus:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8889
    namespace: testapp
  prometheusremotewrite:
    endpoint: http://localhost:9090/api/v1/write
    target_info:
      enabled: true
    remote_write_queue:
      enabled: True
      queue_size: 100000
      num_consumers: 5
  debug:
connectors:
  spanmetrics:
    namespace: span.metrics
  count:

service:
  extensions: [health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: []
      exporters: [otlp, debug, spanmetrics]

    metrics:
      receivers: [spanmetrics, otlp]
      processors: []
      exporters: [prometheus, prometheusremotewrite]

prometheus.yaml
# Copyright The OpenTelemetry Authors
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "otel-collector"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["otel-collector:8889"]

remote_write:
  - url: 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/write'

Would really appreciate if someone could help me on this and sorry for the long code

Your question is a good example of a minimal repro, thank you! I was able to replicate the solution quickly. There are a couple of "quirks". It's unclear to me why Prometheus is configured to remote_write to itself (in prometheus.yml). I commented out the remote_write section (I think) without issue. I also removed the prometheusremotewrite from otel-collector.yaml for the same reason.

With the remote write configurations, you need to add flags when running prometheus in docker-compose file. You need to add a command: section with - --web.enable-remote-write-receiver and then (because you've specified a command value, you must add) - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml.

All that said, while I'm familiar with gRPC and Prometheus, I'm less familiar with OpenTelemetry (but was interested in this question). I'm able to access the Prometheus UI (on 9090) and I'm able to access the Jaeger UI (on 16686). I see traces listed in the Jaeger UI.

@DazWilkin Hi, i'm not sure why i can't view SPM in jaeger, i can't find the root cause of it. I'm also new to monitoring stuff so i'm not quite understand what is remove write btw

@OscarChuaWeiWen why don't you start with an actual working example from Jaeger? https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/tree/main/docker-compose/monitor First make sure it works for you, then try replacing the producer app with your own code.

@YuriShkuro omg it's creator of jaeger, sure i will setup again with the given example, thanks !
